# Distribution algorithm from rectangle to sine

Tags: distribution-theory

I am trying to distribute a constant value along a vector according to sine distribution. I would like to obtain something like this

```
given S = 16        ## constant value, sum of the vector elements
given length = 7    ## length of the vector

result = [1 2 3 4 3 2 1]
```

Comment: What ? Where is the sine ?

Comment: The numbers are just to get the idea of the kind of distribution that I would like to obtain

Comment: What do you mean by "sine distribution"?

Comment: Sine or triangular ? Be more explicit.

Comment: triangular can be also good

Comment: What should happen in the example case, if you increase $S$ by one and keep length constant? Or if you add one to the length and keep $S$ constant?

Comment: @DavideDC: this is not what I call explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\;s_L(k):= \sin\left(\left(k-\frac 12\right)\frac{\pi}L\right)$
then you probably want something like :

$\displaystyle\left(\frac {S\;\cdot s_L(k)}{\sum_{i=1}^L s_L(i)}\right)_{\; k=1\cdots L}$

Example : for $\,L=7\,$ and $\,S=16\,$ we get :
$ [0.79225, 2.2198, 3.2078, 3.5603, 3.2078, 2.2198, 0.79225]$

Which is your result if rounded to the nearest integer.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to implement that in python?

Comment: You may start with :

Comment: import math  (newline)
def si(L):return [math.sin((k+1/2)*math.pi/L) for k in range(L)]

Comment: to get the $\sin$ list and divide by the sum(si(L)) multiplied by $S$. But you have something to do on your own so good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, really useful